# Retrieve TextField value from the ListView

Tags: java, list, listview, wicket

I have ListView.Where iam showing the some records.The ListView contain Lable and TextField.I entered some data in the textField(which is in ListView).On Submit() method,i am trying to retrieve the entered textfield value.But i am not getting the value which i entered in textbox.Please let me know how to get the entered value from textfield?Below is my code.

```
public List<StockCountDetail> getItemEntryDetails() {

        List<StockCountDetail> myStockCountDetailList = new ArrayList<StockCountDetail>();
        List<StockKeepingUnit> mySkuList = MpoBeanFactory.getBean(StockKeepingUnitDAO.class).getByStockLocation(stockLocationModel.getObject());
        myStockCountDetailList.clear();
        for (StockKeepingUnit mySku : mySkuList) {
            StockCountDetail stockCountDetail = new StockCountDetail();
            stockCountDetail.setProduct(mySku.getProduct());
            myStockCountDetailList.add(stockCountDetail);
        }
        return myStockCountDetailList;
    }
myStockCountDetailList = new ListView<StockCountDetail>("itemList", new PropertyModel<List<StockCountDetail>>(
                        StockCountEditPage.this, "itemEntryDetails")) {

            @Override
            protected void populateItem(ListItem<StockCountDetail> aItem) {
                aItem.add(new AttributeAppender("class", true, new Model<String>(aItem.getIndex() % 2 == 0 ? "even" : "odd"), " "));
                aItem.add(new Label("product", aItem.getModelObject().getProduct().getCode()));
                aItem.add(new Label("description", aItem.getModelObject().getProduct().getDescription()));
                aItem.add(new CheckBox("skipFlag", new PropertyModel<Boolean>(aItem.getModel(), "skipFlag")));
                aItem.add(new TextField<Integer>("count", new PropertyModel<Integer>(aItem.getModel(), "count")));
            }
        };
        myStockCountDetailList.setReuseItems(true);
        form.add(myStockCountDetailList);
        setOutputMarkupId(true);
AjaxFallbackButton mySave = new AjaxFallbackButton("save", form) {

            @Override
            protected void onSubmit(AjaxRequestTarget aTarget, Form<?> aForm) {
                saveStockCount();
                aTarget.addComponent(feedbackPanel);
            }

        };
        form.add(mySave);
private void saveStockCount() {
        boolean recordAdded = false;
        for (StockCountDetail myStockCount : myStockCountDetailList.getModelObject()) {
            if (!myStockCount.isSkipFlag()) {
myStockTransaction.setQuantity(new BigDecimal(myStockCount.getCount()));

}
```

here i am not getting the value using myStockCount.getCount() which is the entered value of textbox in listview.let me know how to get value of textbox?

Answer (score 0):

Your `ListView` uses a `PropertyModel` that gets its value from calling `getItemEntryDetails()`.

It you call `myStockCountDetailList.getModelObject()` then the resulting object will come from `this.getItemEntryDetails()` which will return a new `List` with new `StockCountDetail`s.

In order to retain the value, you could store the list in a field.